# Access Violation when using MemoryStream.CopyFrom

Tags: delphi, stream, access-violation

Well this is going to be long!

I made a retransmission scheme for managing dropped UDP packets, for a LAN simulation protocol I am working on.

#### Packet Storage

```
TDataBuffer = record

  PacketID : WORD;
  Packet   : TMemoryStream;

end;
PDataBuffer = ^TDataBuffer;
```

#### Related DataModule Class Members

```
fRxDataPacketList  : TThreadList20;
fTxDataPacketList  : TThreadList20;

procedure CreateDataBuffer
          (PacketID : WORD; Packet : TMemoryStream;
           var DataBuffer : PDataBuffer);

procedure DestroyDataBuffer
          (var DataBuffer : PDataBuffer);

procedure AddPacketToPacketList
          (PacketID : WORD; Packet : TMemoryStream;
           RecievedPacket : Boolean);

function  GetPacketFromTxDataPacketList
          (PacketID : WORD; var Packet : TMemoryStream): Boolean;
```

TThreadList20: It is my own thread friendly, encryption and compression supporting wrapper class for TList.

There is another procedure for processing the Rx side which doesn't concern my question so I am skipping it.

#### Creation

```
procedure TDataModuleClient.CreateDataBuffer
          (PacketID : WORD; Packet : TMemoryStream; 
           var DataBuffer : PDataBuffer);

begin

  New (DataBuffer);
  DataBuffer.PacketID := PacketID;
  DataBuffer.Packet   := TMemoryStream.Create;

  if Assigned (Packet) then 
  begin

    DataBuffer.Packet.CopyFrom (Packet,Packet.Size); // NO AV HERE
    DataBuffer.Packet.Position := 0;

  end;

end;
```

#### Destruction

```
procedure TDataModuleClient.DestroyDataBuffer
          (var DataBuffer : PDataBuffer);
begin

  DataBuffer.Packet.Free;
  Dispose (DataBuffer);

end;
```

#### Addition To List

```
procedure TDataModuleClient.AddPacketToDataPacketList
          (PacketID : WORD; Packet : TMemoryStream; RecievedPacket : Boolean);
var
  DataBuffer : PDataBuffer;

begin

  CreateDataBuffer (PacketID,Packet,DataBuffer);

  if RecievedPacket then
    fRxDataPacketList.Add (TObject (DataBuffer))

  else
  begin

    fTxDataPacketList.Lock;

    try

      fTxDataPacketList.Add (TObject (DataBuffer));

      if fRxDataPacketList.Count = 21 then
      begin

        DataBuffer := PDataBuffer (fTxDataPacketList [0]);

        DestroyDataBuffer (DataBuffer);
        fTxDataPacketList.Delete (0);

      end;

    finally fTxDataPacketList.Unlock;
    end;

  end;

end;
```

#### Extraction From List

```
function  TDataModuleClient.GetPacketFromTxDataPacketList
          (PacketID : WORD; var Packet : TMemoryStream): Boolean;
var
  DataBuffer : PDataBuffer;
  I          : Integer;

begin

  Result := False;
  fTxDataPacketList.Lock;

  try

    for I := fTxDataPacketList.Count - 1 downto 0 do
    begin

      DataBuffer := PDataBuffer (fTxDataPacketList [I]);

      if DataBuffer.PacketID < PacketID then
      begin

        DestroyDataBuffer (DataBuffer);
        fTxDataPacketList.Delete (I);

      end
      else if DataBuffer.PacketID = PacketID then
      begin

        Result := True;

        Packet := TMemoryStream.Create;

        Packet.CopyFrom
        (DataBuffer.Packet,DataBuffer.Packet.Size); // AV HERE
        Packet.Position := 0;

        DestroyDataBuffer (DataBuffer);
        fTxDataPacketList.Delete (I);

        break;

      end;

    end;

  finally fTxDataPacketList.Unlock;
  end;

end;
```

Packet: Output Variable.

Please help me out, I know it looks like a tall order to deduce something thanks to the amount of code.

Comment: 1. I tried to access the size property of the stream which returned the correct size. 2. I also tried using conversion to TIdbytes and moving it to another buffer and then converting them back to no avail.

Comment: Why are you trying to monitor and resend UDP packets?  UDP is send and forget, it doesn't care if the packets never arrive.  If you want to make sure they get there, have you considered just using the TCP protocol?  That's managed already and takes care of retransmission for you.  Also, when you are passing in the Packet to the function, is it created beforehand, and is it positioned properly?

Comment: In the create function, its created in the function. In the add function it is created in another function and sent for storage only.

Comment: I need UDP because it gives me less ping in the range of 50-150ms to users sitting in the US and Europe, while tcp often goes above 650ms in peak hours.

Comment: You're creating a stream, copying from a source stream, and then destroying the source stream. You could avoid all that by simply *moving* the stream from the data buffer into the packet: `Packet := DataBuffer.Packet; DataBuffer.Packet := nil`.

Comment: Yes, that can be done. let me check.

Comment: It works when extracted in the add method but doesn't when it is extracted in get.

Answer (score 2):

Based on this limited code, I am making some guesses:

1) the input `Packet` that is being passed to `GetPacketFromTxDataPacketList()` has probably not actually been instantiated yet before you call `CopyFrom()`. That would account for the AV.

2) since the `Packet` parameter is declared as a `var`, that suggests to me that it is an output parameter that `GetPacketFromTxDataPacketList()` is supposed to create and return, instead of having the caller create the `TMemoryStream` and pass it into `GetPacketFromTxDataPacketList()` to be filled with data.  That would also play into #1, since `GetPacketFromTxDataPacketList()` is not creating a new `TMemoryStream` object, it is assuming the object has already been created beforehand.

Comment: 1) It has been instantiated in the calling function. And you deduced it correctly it is indeed being used as an output parameter. Anyways, I'll put it in the function and check.